# draggable on ScalaJS removeEventListener does not work

Tags: scala, scala.js

based on that js demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wfbY8/737/

```scala
class Draggable(element: HTMLDivElement) {

  var offX: Double = 0
  var offY: Double = 0

  val divMove = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    //element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.style.top = (e.clientY-offY) + "px"
    element.style.left = (e.clientX-offX) + "px"
  }

  val mouseDown = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    offY = e.clientY - element.offsetTop
    offX = e.clientX - element.offsetLeft
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", divMove, useCapture = true)
    println("added")
  }

  val mouseUp = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", divMove, useCapture = true)
     println("removed")
  }

  def addListeners(){
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, useCapture = false)
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, useCapture = false)

  }

  addListeners()

}
```

From the client code I use it like:

```scala
  val panelElem = document.getElementById(COMPONENT_ID).asInstanceOf[HTMLDivElement]
  if (draggable == null) {
    draggable = new Draggable(panelElem)
  }
```

I see "added" and "removed" on my log. But the element still movable (when I move mouse without pressing it) for me as if I did not removed mousemove event from the listener (on  mouseUp).

I wonder why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're effectively converting the Scala function (the lambda) into a JS function separately for `add` and `remove`. In Scala.js, Scala functions are implicitly *converted* to JS functions as needed. However, the conversion yields a different JS function every time (it does not have the same *identity*). Therefore, the function you're trying to remove is not *the same* as the one you added, and of course that has no effect.

You can fix this by forcing the conversion to happen early, so that then you add and remove the same function. To do so, simply add an explicit type to your function `val`s as JS functions:

```scala
  val divMove: js.Function1[MouseEvent, Unit] = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    ...
  }
```

This way, the conversion from Scala function to JS function happens only once, and it is the same JS function that is given to `add`- and `removeEventListener`.

Comment: yes. it works now. Just expected to happen it once (the conversion)..since it it is val. Now it is a little boilerplate

Comment: It does happen once because it's a `val` with the fix. But without, the `val` evaluates once and stores a *Scala* function. It is only converted later when passing it to `add/removeEventListener`, and therefore the conversion is done several times. The ascription only forces the conversion to be applied as part of evaluating the `val` (hence, once) instead of later.